# How do I print multiple variables in a line of code?

Tags: python

```
!/usr/bin/env python3

import random
import socket
import time
import sys
import os

print ('Ping Of Death')
os.system("clear")
print

ip_death = input("ip:")
packetsize = input("size:")
print (ip_death)

os.system("ping ip_death, -s packetsize ")
```

and the output I get is

```
ping: ip_death,: Name or service not known
```

I know the variables are defined because of `print (ip_death)` that I have tested and always comes out with my input.

I'm new to python and just wondering how I can run both of these variables in the in one command. If wonder I'm trying to run `Ping example.com -s "size of packet"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to format the string:

```
os.system("ping {}, -s {}".format(ip_death, packet_size))
```

You can also verify you're doing the right thing by printing the command before executing it:

```
command = "ping {}, -s {}".format(ip_death, packet_size)
print(command) # see that its what you wanted to execute
os.system(command)
```

Currently you just baked the names into the strings. Python doesn't automagically know what it should format and what it shouldn't.

Also - black hat hacking is bad <3

Comment: I used both of those commands to the best of my ablity and still coming out with errors keeps saying "invalid syntax" and I show the variables work because they spit out when  I put print (ip_death)
print (packetsize)

Answer (score 2):

```
os.system(f"ping {ip_death}, -s {packetsize} ")
```

You can use `f-strings` to insert a variable directly into a string. `f-strings` are defined by `f"{variable}"`

Note:

```
os.system(f"ping {ip_death}, -s {packetsize} ")
```

Will still fail, the comma will throw an error in `cmd`,

> Ping request could not find host 192.168.0.1,. Please check the name and try again.

You need to remove the comma for it to work;

```
os.system(f"ping {ip_death} -s {packetsize} ")
```

> > ping 192.168.0.1 -s 1
>
> Pinging 192.168.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
>
> Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
>
> > Timestamp: 192.168.0.1 : 4742664

Comment: I did what you told me but keeps bringing up In valid syntax.

Comment: File "/home/pen/Desktop/ddoser.py", line 17
    os.system(f"ping {ip_death} -s {packetsize} ")
                                                ^

Comment: if you cant see where the arrow is point it's at the far right  "