# Python variable Name or service not known

Tags: python

I have a problem where running this code which seems to be right to me, but it says that my variable cannot be known

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random
import socket
import time
import sys
import os

print ('Ping Of Death')
os.system("clear")
print() 
ipdeath = input("ip:")
packetsize = input("size:")
print (ipdeath)
global ipdeath , packetsize
os.system("ping {ipdeath} -s {packetsize} ")
```

The Variable works because it prints out of the print (ipdeath) but not out of the os.system("ping {ipdeath} -s {packetsize} ")

just returns with an error that says

```
ping: {ipdeath}: Name or service not known
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `global`

And you're [missing a formatted string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59996634/how-do-i-print-multiple-variables-in-a-line-of-code)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

print ('Ping Of Death')
os.system("clear")
print() 
ipdeath = input("ip:")
packetsize = input("size:")
os.system(f"ping {ipdeath} -s {packetsize} ")
```

You're not capturing the output of the ping command, so that's why nothing would be printed for it (hint: use subprocess module instead of `os`

Comment: when giving me the format and running it, it comes out with a syntax error because of the "f" in the last line because when I take it out I get my original error, does the the "f" have anything to do with it?

Comment: I did try to use subprocess using this command subprocess.run("ping" ['ipdeath'] -s ['packetsize'], capture_output=True)

Comment: but only coming out with a TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Why did you switch to square brackets?

Comment: And yes, the f is necessary. Lookup f-strings in the Python documentation

Comment: I think you meant `subprocess.run(["ping", ipdeath, '-s' packetsize], capture_output=True)`

Comment: @cricket_007 It is not certain that the OP uses Python 3.6 or higher, which is needed for f-strings.

Comment: @Selcuk if you look at the comment, the error is clearly the square brackets `subprocess.run("ping"['ipdeath']`

Comment: @cricket_007 I wasn't talking about the error. Your answer only applies to Python 3.6 or higher. Maybe you should indicate that.